# Jatayu's fight with indra

Tags: ramayana, indra, jatayu

The answer to this question [How was Jatayu able to fight with Ravana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22782/how-was-jatayu-able-to-fight-with-ravana)  says that jatayu went to fight indra. Any description available for that fight?

Answer (score 1):

I think the earlier answer, the OP is referring to, gave a slight different meaning of the sloka from Aranya Kanda  of Ramayana, in which Sampati describes his journey to Sun, along with his brother.

That is why a confusion arose.  Go through the meaning of the sloka from a different site.

https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga58/kishkindha_58_frame.htm

> पुरा वृत्र वधे वृत्ते स च अहम् च जय एषिणौ |
>   आदित्यम् उपयातौ स्वो ज्वलंतम् रश्मि मालिनम् || ४-५८-४
>
> "Once, **when the elimination of demon Vritta was taking place at the hand of Indra**, we two eagle-brothers sportively desiring to surpass each other flew sunward, and we have gone very near to the scorch-rayed sun...

So the 2 brothers Sampati and Jatayu flew, when the fight between Vritta and Indra was taking place.  It was not about the fight between Jatayu and Indra.